# What's the difference between "rind", "peel", and "skin"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I usually see **rind**, **peel**, and **skin** used interchangeably, But is there any meaning behind them? For example:

> banana peel vs banana skin vs banana rind

- Which one should we use for each thing?
- And also which verb should we use for each thing?

Comment: This seems like more of a science question, not so much an ELL question.

Comment: There's no difference between a *banana peel* and a *banana peel*. Did you intend to say something like *banana peel vs banana skin* instead?

Comment: Yes, these are very similar but they don't always exchange equally for each other. Can you reference the definitions in your question so that it is easier to point out their differences? Start of an answer: citrus fruits and melons are usually paired with 'rind'; banana always with peel; apples, pears,plums, cherries, grapes are either skin or peel.

Comment: *banana rind* is unusual,  @xiota's answer explains why.  It's also unusual *to skin a banana* or indeed *to skin* any other piece of fruit; *skinning* is, usually, done to animals.  Or websites.

Comment: Typically a skin is only a "peel" after it's been removed; i.e. after the fruit's been peeled. Skin vs. rind is dependent on thickness; however, a (say, pumpkin) rind can have an outer skin layer.

Comment: I don't recall ever rinding my knees as a child.  Skinned them plenty of times.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of fruit, there's enough overlap that the words are functionally synonymous. Some fruits are paired with certain words by convention, as [Mitch](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510373/whats-the-difference-between-rind-peel-and-skin#comment1237846_510373) comments, but it's *often* still acceptable to use either of the other words. Skin includes "outer coatings" that may not be thick or firm enough to be considered rinds.

- [**Rind**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rind)

  > - a thick and firm outer coat or covering, as of certain fruits, cheeses, and meats: watermelon rind; orange rind; bacon rind.
  > - the bark of a tree.
- [**Peel**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/peel) – Though not in the definition, the word is often used after removal, as [Spencer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510373/whats-the-difference-between-rind-peel-and-skin#comment1237863_510373) notes.

  > the ***skin* or *rind* of a fruit**, vegetable, etc.
- [**Skin**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/skin) is a general word to refer to outer coatings. It has uses beyond fruit.

  > - the external covering or integument of an animal body, especially when soft and flexible.
  > - any integumentary covering, casing, outer coating, or surface layer, as an investing membrane, the ***rind* or *peel* of fruit**, or a film on liquid:

Answer (score 1):

As a noun, for external coverings of plants or animal parts (usually food), the three have their nuances: 'rind' is used more often for thicker or tougher things like citrus fruits and melons, and 'skin' or 'peel' for thinner things like apples, potatoes, or grapes. 'skin' and 'peel are often interchangeable for plant products, but 'peel' is never used for animal products.

As verbs, 'rind' is never used, and 'peel' is never used for animals. The verb is used for a fruit just as the noun: for example, you can peel or skin a grape and likewise have the grape peel or skin, but you can only peel a banana resulting in a banana peel (skin sound weird for both).

Examples:

- the rind of a brie
- melon, orange, lemon rind
- pork rinds (fried pig skin)
- orange, lemon peel
- banana peel
- potato peel (but 'potato skins' as an edible dish)
- apple/pear/grape skin/peel

If it isn't in that list it is not commonly said.

Comment: If both "rind" and "peel" are usually used for "orange" and "lemon", it'd be better to put them in a separate bullet, i.e. - orange/lemon peel/rind, and leave only "melon" in the list of fruits which always use "rind".

Answer (score 0):

"peel" can be the skin of the fruit, but also the verb meaning "rind" can only be used as a noun. Also, there is a slight difference in meaning between the two words: Rind is usually harder than peel.\